# Too glossy texture

Tags: texturing

I´ve made two textures following a tutorial, and I´ve mixed them up with vertex paint to texture the hill. The thing is that the cliff part is too shiny and I don´t know how to low it down....
I can attach a node screenshot: [image: Nodes]

[image: Render]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**Roughness** input in **PBR_Shader** is responsible for, well... Roughness. Or as you describe it shininess. It is controlled by **Math > Subtract** in your case.

I can't tell you what exact values you need to use as I don't have those node groups. You can even disconnect **Subtract** at all and set Roughness as the same for both parts.

Comment: @achaba If my answer helped you please consider to accept it and/or upvote ;)

Comment: Sorry, I´m new in this forum... how can I accept and upvote, @LukeD?

Comment: @achaba here you have everything about it: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour :)